# What to use Process Builder or WorkFlow rule?

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have to do update a picklist field on related `Case` records when an modification to `Account` record is detected.

Like to hear from experts...

Comment: Perhaps you can change the question to, what are the reasons to use workflow rules over process builder when updating a picklist field.

Comment: i will change the question title but why i got 2 down-votes for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating children records is a feature of the process builder but it is not possible using Workflow rules. So I would definitely recommend using the Process Builder in your sceneario. Instructions from help [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000213419&language=en_US):

> The Process Builder allows you to update child records whenever the
>   parent record is modified. Here's how:
>
> Create a new Process.
>
> Select the Record you would like to update. Example record in account
>   Object.
>
> Define the Criteria.
>
> In "Immediate Action," select Update Records.
>
> Click on the "Object" drop down: Select the Account record that
>   started your process and Select a record related to the Account:
>
> These are radio buttons and only one can be selected and to update
>   child records you need to select send option “Select a record related
>   to the Account”
>
> In "Find a field," look for the child object name you want to update.
>
> If child object is a Custom Object the name would contain "__r" at the
>   end.
>
> Select the Child Object name, and then click Save.
>
> In "Set new value" section, define the field that you want to update
>   in child records and what value it should contain
>
> Click Save.
>
> Similar steps can be used to update lookup fields using process
>   builder too.